# Saving excelsheet as Googlesheet with same access rights to user & sharable link

Tags: excel, google-sheets, r-googlesheets

hv uploaded an excelsheet on a Google drive and have shared to multiple users with shareable link for updation. Now tht i wants to restrict users to update on their specific cells only for tht I needed to save as Googlesheet.. but the new file is getting created.

So I wants help how can I create Google sheet with same access rights to users & same sharable link.

Can't the version history be overlapped on same file frm Excel(.xlsx) to Google sheet with same user sharable links and access rights.

Comment: Are you looking for [Protect content in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308980?hl=en)?

Comment: @idfurw You see tht is the requirement bt that functionality works on Googlesheet format not on sheet with .xlsx extension.

Comment: Then I think there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: @idfurw Thn suggest if it's there any hardway.. I can attempt any advance setups. But thing is sharable link should remain same.

Comment: Why are you not converting the .xlsx into spreadsheet at the very first step (before sharing)?

Comment: @idfurw you mean googlesheet.? yaa well tht was a mistake, didn't know Google version convertability issues.. Actually tht is the question I raised on overflow.. What to do now.